# How to remove some functions in a template specification for void type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `TriggerEvent`:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
class TriggerEvent<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>
{
 public:
  using EventCallback = std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>;
  using InvokeCallback = std::function<bool(const ReturnType&)>;

  void Subscribe(EventCallback&& callback);
  void Clear();

  void Invoke(ArgumentTypes&&... args);
  void Invoke(ArgumentTypes&&... args, InvokeCallback&& invoke_callback);

 private:
  std::mutex access_mtx_;
  std::list<EventCallback> event_callbacks_;
};
```

I can't compile object of this class with template `TriggerEvent<void(T)`> because the `void` type can't be used for `InvokeCallback` alias and in `Invoke` method with callback in its implementation.
The alias and the method is for `ReturnType` that differs from `void`. How can I remove the alias and the method from class when the `ReturnType` is `void`?

Comment: Specialization for the `void` case?

Comment: It's not just a matter of removing the alias. You also need to make sure that the rest of the code actually works. What method is best will depend on the rest of your code. SFINAE and template specializations are your two main options.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, you mean creation of the second class of TriggerEvent with void specialization? I know about it, but i'm trying to find an efficient way, because in that case I need to copy and paste a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper template to generate the proper invoke callback type:

- `bool(T)`
- `bool()` when `T` == `void`

Like so:

```
template <typename ReturnType>
struct invoke_callback_ref {
  using type = bool(const ReturnType&);
};

template <>
struct invoke_callback_ref<void> {
  using type = bool();
};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
class TriggerEvent {
public:
  using EventCallback = std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>;
  using InvokeCallback = std::function<typename invoke_callback_ref<ReturnType>::type>;
  . . .
```

---

However, remember that `std::function` comes with run-time overhead.

I would use `std::function` only when its unavoidable - like when storing event callbacks in a list. In all other places use a Callable type directly. That eliminates the issue of dealing with references to `void` and you can just use `if constexpr` to invoke a `void` callback.

For example:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
class TriggerEvent {
public:
  using EventCallback = std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>;

  template<typename T>
  void Subscribe(T&& callback) {
    event_callbacks_.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(callback));
  }

  void Invoke(ArgumentTypes&&... args) {
    for (auto& cb : event_callbacks_) cb(args...);
  }

  template<typename T>
  void Invoke(ArgumentTypes&&... args, T&& invoke_callback) {
    for (auto& cb : event_callbacks_) {
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<ReturnType, void>) {
        cb(args...);
        invoke_callback();
      } else {
        invoke_callback(cb(args...));
      }
    }
  }

private:
  std::list<EventCallback> event_callbacks_;
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OHynPGrhzJWnmgxs)